# Crash Errors: Native crash at /system/lib/libc.so in /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12), /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)

Tags: android

Getting following error and app crashes after providing update. Home activity contain listview with 50 images. Please suggest for the resolution.

```
        Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/kltevzw/kltevzw:6.0.1/MMB29M/G900VVRS2DQB2:user/release-keys'
        Revision: '14'
        ABI: 'arm'
        pid: 12922, tid: 12922, name: m.ex.exp  >>> com.ex.exp <<<
        signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
        Abort message: 'art/runtime/class_linker.cc:2502] Check failed: dex_cache.Get() != nullptr Failed to allocate dex cache for /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk:classes3.dex'
            r0 00000000  r1 0000327a  r2 00000006  r3 b6f13b84
            r4 b6f13b8c  r5 b6f13b3c  r6 00000001  r7 0000010c
            r8 b3fbf800  r9 b3fbde44  sl 9927d3db  fp b3fa3480
            ip 00000006  sp becac340  lr b6c74c09  pc b6c76ff8  cpsr 40070010

        backtrace:
            #00 pc 00041ff8  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
            #01 pc 0003fc05  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
            #02 pc 0001c38b  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
            #03 pc 00019609  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
            #04 pc 0001755c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
            #05 pc 003341ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+228)
            #06 pc 000f477b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226)
            #07 pc 000f0a51  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7BarrierD2Ev+216)
            #08 pc 0035c201  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+188)
            #09 pc 00334275  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+428)
            #10 pc 000f477b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+2226)
            #11 pc 0012fb57  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker15RegisterDexFileERKNS_7DexFileE+546)
            #12 pc 001360b1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+704)
            #13 pc 001363b7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE.part.589+522)
            #14 pc 00136c7b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+50)
            #15 pc 00139b31  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+160)
            #16 pc 0013b8f5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker13ResolveMethodERKNS_7DexFileEjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEEPNS_9ArtMethodENS_10InvokeTypeE+140)
            #17 pc 003fc9e5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker13ResolveMethodEPNS_6ThreadEjPNS_9ArtMethodENS_10InvokeTypeE.part.125+68)
            #18 pc 00400805  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickResolutionTrampoline+2636)
            #19 pc 000eab23  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_resolution_trampoline+34)
            #20 pc 049eb5f3  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x3209000)
```